# sql query- id and name display

Tags: sql

There are two tables table A got Id , name

Table B got Mgr ID and Emp ID.

[image]

[image]

I need data like

[image]

Comment: Did you try anything before asking SO to write the code for you? What problems did you encounter while trying that?

Comment: I didn't join the same table twice. I was getting mgr name but was getting stuck in emp name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join twice:

```
select
    b.mgr_id,
    a_mgr.name mgr_name,
    b.emp_id,
    a_emp.name emp_name
from tableB b
inner join tableA a_mgr on a_mgr.id = b.mgr_id
inner join tableA a_emp on a_emp.id = b.emp_id
```